# why type name is not allowed?

Tags: c++, enums

I want that when passing a certain enumeration property, the corresponding operator with type checking is output, here is a simple code example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
//#include <memory>

enum MessageType : uint16_t
{
    Display,
    Warning,
    Error
};

#define MESSAGE(_MessageType, _Text)\
    if((_MessageType == Display) && (typeid(_MessageType).name() == MessageType))\
    {\
        std::cout<<"Display: "<<_Text;\
    }\
    else if((_MessageType == Warning) && (typeid(_MessageType).name() == MessageType))\
    {\
        std::cout<<"Warning: "<<_Text;\
    }\
    else if ((_MessageType == Warning) && (typeid(_MessageType).name() == MessageType))\
    {\
        std::cout<<"Error: "<<_Text;\
    }\
    else\
        return

int main()
{
    MESSAGE(Display, "Text!"); // type name is not allowed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: names with leading `_` followed by a capital letter are reserved. Your code has undefined behavior

Comment: Why is `MESSAGE` here a macro instead of a function?

Comment: `MessageType` is a type. Types are not operands for the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::type_info::name` returns a c-string. `MessageType` is not a string, its the name of a type. You can compare the string returned from `typeid(_MessageType).name()` to the string returned from `typeid(MessageType).name()`.

However, identifiers starting with leading `_` followed by capital letter are reseved. If you use them your code has undefined behavior. Moreover `main` is not `void` you must return an `int`.

And last but not least, you don't need `typeid` when you can use `constexpr if` and `std::is_same`. A simple function instead of macro would also make it much easier to get a compiler error when the type does not match. Currently your check for the right type is made at runtime. I see no reason to use a macro here, the same could be achieved without one.

Comment: If `name` returns a c-string, will `operator==` necessarily be an accurate comparison?

Comment: @NathanPierson wasnt sure, had to check, it is implementation defined.